# replace a long chunk of repeating query text with a constant wo dynamic execution?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a pretty complicated piece of `CASE` syntax that repeats several times.
The procedure is working just fine but it's becoming hard to read, and it's making surrounding syntax also harder to read.

Is there a way to put this part of code in a constant then just write the constant name in a query without resorting to dynamic execution?

eg.

```
DECLARE @CASE = 'LONG UGLY CASE STATEMENT'
SELECT Column1, Column, Column3, @CASE, Column4
FROM Table1 WHERE Conditions
```

Comment: Always write query based on performance execution rather than formatting style..In your case you can make use of dynamic query but why you want to do that better format the query.

Comment: Is the logic repeated many times within a single query, or across multiple ones?

Comment: Logic is repeated multiple times across same stored procedure, but not within same SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds similar to needing to code for DRY (don't repeat yourself) principles.
Perhaps code like this will help.

In each case, `Z` represents the complex `CASE` code
Option 1 should be more performant than 2.

```
/*
    DRY Option 1
*/
;WITH SimplifiedCaseCTE AS
(
    SELECT   A
            ,B
            ,Z  =   CASE
                        WHEN A LIKE 'moo%' THEN 1
                        ELSE 2
                    END
    FROM TableA
)
SELECT   A
        ,B
        ,Z
        ,X = Z * 10
FROM SimplifiedCaseCTE

/*
    DRY Option 2
*/
SELECT   TA.A
        ,TA.B
        ,CA.Z
        ,X = CA.Z * 10
FROM TableA     TA
CROSS 
APPLY
(
    SELECT Z =  CASE
                    WHEN A LIKE 'moo%' THEN 1
                    ELSE 2
                END
)               CA
```